# plot() | qplot(..., geom="boxplot",...) unwanted ordering of factors (R 3.1.2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe consisting of 2 columns, one a factor column("C7":"C20") and the other is numeric.  When I try to plot the dataframe, the ordering of the factors occurs alphabetically, i.e. starts at C10...C20,C7,C8,C9.  I am trying to get the ordering as sequential, i.e. C7 -> C20.

I have tried to order the factors with the factor function:

```
X2 <- factor(X1$column1, levels:c("C7", "C8", "C9", ... , "C20"))
```

edit: {I have realised the code above is incorrect.  See comment below for elaboration}.

but this changes the whole data frame to factor class,  and plotting functions cannot recognise factors for boxplots - 
e.g. "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor"

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you convert one column of a data.frame into factor then it shouldn't affect the rest of the columns. Are you sure it is not a matrix? In your code above you just assign a factor to variable X2. Is sorting the problem or plotting the data.frame? It is unclear. Maybe you need to create a reproducible example in order to show us exactly what you need.

Comment: I apologise if I have confused you.  I am new to R.  The problem lies in plotting the data.frame as a boxplot.  The numeric y-axis is fine.  The ordering of the factors on the x-axis however is not as desired i.e. C7-C20.  Instead the x-axis is ordered starting at C10...C20,C7,C8,C9.    The data is structured such that there are approximately 100 observations for each factor.  I see where I went wrong in the code above... X2 only consists of the factor variable, and not the numeric variable.  The class of the data is a data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to change the class of a variable within a dataframe, which has sorted my problem out.  I needed to reference the variable within the dataframe to change its class:

```
df$col1 <- factor(df$col1, levels= c("C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", ..., "C20"))
```

Comment: I posted an alternative with `mixedsort` in case you have 100 factors for example in which case it would have taken you ages to just type those. As an alternative :). But this is the idea thus the upvote.

Comment: Thanks LyzandeR.   Yes, typing out C7...C10 with all the inverted commas etc, was irritating.  The `mixedsort()` function is VERY useful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ok so you need to work with `mixedsort` from the `gtools` package in order to do that:

`mixedsort` sorts alpha-numeric strings according to their number part, i.e. in this case it is exactly what you need.

**Example Data**

```
x <- factor(  rep(c('c1','c2','c10','c11'),each=10))
y <- runif(40)
df <- data.frame(y,x)

boxplot(y ~ x, data=df)
```

If you plot this data you ll see I got the same problem as you:

[image]

**Solution**

But if you sort the levels using `mixedsort` then the problem is fixed:

```
library(gtools)


df <- data.frame(y,x)
#essentially this is the only line (below) that makes the difference. It just
#orders the factor's levels in the way you want
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels=mixedsort(levels(df$x)))

boxplot(y ~ x, data=df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution : plot first the data values without x axis and then add it with the right label

```
df = data.frame(fact = paste0("C",c(7:20)), num = runif(14))
plot(df$num, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at = 1:length(df$num), labels = df$fact)
```

Then you can change `type =` in `plot` to change the type of plot (points, line, steps, etc.)

Comment: Thanks clemlaflemme.  question:  if I label the axis with an independent dataframe, how will R know which data observation belongs to which group?

Comment: sure there is no control, I wasn't aware about `mixedsort` proposed by @LyzandeR. It is a better solution

Comment: Thanks for your consideration clemmlaflemme.  Your code will be useful in the future.  Thanks.